# Dynamic API Versioning with NSwag like with Swashbuckle

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, openapi, nswag

I'm trying to implement api-versioning using .NET 6.0 and NSwag and it works fine, but I can't get automatic document generation to work.

**How can the following be done with NSwag?** -> https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/API-Documentation#aspnet-core

All examples I can find manually call `AddOpenApiDocument` for every version, but I would like to do that automatically for every version like shown in the docs for Swashbuckle.
For now I use an intermediate `IServiceProvider`, but this generates valid warnings:

```
var versionDescriptionProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();
foreach (var description in versionDescriptionProvider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
{
    builder.Services.AddOpenApiDocument(document =>
        {
            document.DocumentName = description.GroupName;
            document.ApiGroupNames = new[] { description.GroupName };
        });
}
```

Comment: Do you want to manually switch the API version according to your needs in the upper right corner?

Comment: @Chaodeng Yes, exactly, that's the target...

Comment: You can refer to this post, it may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45238908/nswag-multiple-document-endpoint

Comment: @Chaodeng I only see examples manually calling `AddOpenApiDocument`/`UseSwagger` multiple times there...

Comment: Any suggestions so far?

Comment: @Qhori No, still using the "warning generating version"....

Comment: Looking for the same information. Still using it like this? I came over an example for Swashbuckle that somewhat looks like your solution 
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/ms/samples/aspnetcore/SwaggerSample/ConfigureSwaggerOptions.cs